# SPF records problem

Tags: postfix

i'm using ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS in my VPS and i'm trying to set up spf records i have used perl and python methods but no one works for me  when i send email test to spf checker it says Result: none (No applicable sender policy available)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be quite confused. SPF records are DNS entries and have nothing to do with perl or python, and are only tangentially related to postfix (postfix might check them, but does not create any).

For an example spf record that uses a few of the mechanisms in the standard, you could look at the booking.com spf record:

```
$ dig -t TXT booking.com | grep spf
booking.com.        875 IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx/25 ip4:154.54.96.0/28 include:priceline.com include:sendgrid.net ?all"
```